# How to set the Python 2 Preference in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

**PyCharm** is a good IDE, but its code hinting is not so intelligent. For example, when I use it to write Python2 code (the setting of my *interpreter path* can tell PyCharm this), I type ***prin***, which I want PyCharm to give me a hint of ***print***, however, the first prompt is ***print()***, which is a Python3 style of function **print**.
Is there any setting in PyCharm that I can tell it not to give me Python3 prompt when I am writing Python2 code (and not to give me Python2 prompt when I am writing Python3 code)?

My PyCharm version is 2.7.1

Comment: Probably a regression of http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-1275.

Comment: Maybe this is just something where PyCharm is not so perfect. I begin to put up with this problem, to see whether PyCharm can be improved in the future.

Comment: It's just a bug that will be fixed, we've reopened PY-1275, please follow it for updates.

Comment: THX~Looking forward to its being fixed.

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps, you should select python 2.x interpreter for the project (File Menu - Settings - Project - Project Interpreter).

Comment: THX~ The Project Interpreter has already been set as python 2.7, but this problem stays the same.

Comment: I have been got the same problem. By default I work with python 3.4, but, for a specific job I need the Python 2.7. I set in pycharm, but it keeps loading the 3.4 interpreter. 

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Simply set the Python Interpreter from **3.x** to **2.x** as you want.

Steps of
**PyCharm Version: Community Edition 2016.3.2**

1. You need to install the interpreter first.
2. Then go to *File -> Settings -> Project:dev -> Project Interpreter* -> Set Python 2.7 
   [image]
3. Now go to *Run -> Edit Configuration* -> and set python Interpreter 2.7 here as given in the snapshot below-
   [image: Python Interpreter 2.7]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

Run->Edit Configurations, Replace all Py3 to Py2

I use PyCharm 3.0.1